# Echo text directly after variable

Tags: php, echo

I have 2 variables named `$min` and `$sec`.

`If $min = 5` and `$sec = 15` I want to print this `"5m 15s"`, `echo "$min m $sec s";`

But that gives "5 m 15 s".  How do I get rid of the blank space?

Comment: he  can't do it. Someone else did. Answers are not totally wrong but still downvotes. o.O

Comment: No there is one answer that is not downvoted.

Comment: All the answers were downvoted. I was keeping me updated with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo $min."m ".$sec."s";` is one way of doing it

Answer (score 15):

You can use braces to do this, same as many shells:

```
$min = 7;
$sec = 2;
echo "${min}m ${sec}s";
```

The output of that is:

```
7m 2s
```

The braces serve to delineate the variable name from the following text in situations where the "greedy" nature of variables would cause problems.

So, while `$minm` tries to give you the contents of the `minm` variable, `${min}m` will give you the contents of the `min` variable followed by the literal `m`.

Comment: paxdiablo can you tell me why braces are for? I am just beginner of PHP. Never seen them in echo statement ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `sprintf` which I would prefer, especially in the context of i18n.

Comment: @AspiringAqib They are used to wrap around the name of the variables to distinguish them from normal string characters. You can use `echo "{$min}m {$sec}s";` as well.

Comment: thanks got it ;) and also tried. Should i add example in your answer? or you can yourself http://codepad.viper-7.com/HHyGhi

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib. If you're starting out, it's a good idea to make it a habit to always surround your interpolated variables with braces. Aside from solving the issue at hand, the braces also ensure more complicated expressions like `"{$a['cup']['cake']}"` or `"{$a->cup->cake}"` will work as expected. Without the braces, both these examples would trigger fatal errors.

Comment: @cleong I realized that instead of confusing yourself writing code you can also use it and do you know same thing in JAVASCRIPT like braces?

Answer (score 1):

u can try this

```
  echo $min."m ".$sec."s ";
```

edit>

```
the output is 
 5m 15s
```